# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Again, serialization fails, a bool becomes a string when reading it back from blobbed field

Tags: c#, mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have asked questions regarding serialization and deserialization before regarding ServiceStack OrmLite, and I am not sure if this is the same issues I've had before, but I don't think so.

Basically, I have a `public Dictionary<string, object> _CustomProperties` where I store some random data.

I add random data to this dictionary like this:

```
ms._SetCustomProperty<bool>("ConvertedContactItems", true);
```

like so:

[image]

and this is blobbed using OrmLite, like this:

[image]

When I read it back (using Untyped API), I do as below:

```
bool hasConvertedContactItems = actor._GetCustomProperty<bool>("ConvertedContactItems");
```

but the boolean `true` is now a string, not a bool:

[image]

The question is: what am I doing wrong? I have a slight feeling this might be an answer that sounds the same as before, but I am not quite sure about it.

**UPDATE 1**

Below is a `Dictionary<string, object>` serialized using JsvSerializer in OrmLite. I thought that since it cannot properly deserialze a boolean, it for sure cannot deserialize a custom object. Well, it seems that custom objects have sometimes the type info in there. The `CustomerSettings` gets correctly deserialized, but bool, datetime etc, does not.

So, if type info is added for custom objects, why not for primitives so we can deserialize them correctly? (Too bloated? Then why for custom objects?)

```
{
    MyBoolProp:True, // <-- why not emit type info, like CustomerSettings below?
    MyDateTime:2018-08-01T22:49:58.7586897+02:00, // <-- why not emit type info
    Settings:
    {
        __type:"Commons.CustomerSettings,Commons",
        NotifStarted:False,
        NotifFinished:True
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that using a json serializer is the only way to resolve this issue? Or are there other ways?

Answer (score 2):

The serialized output does not contain any Type information so if you try to deserialize it into an `object` it doesn't know what Type to deserialize into so it leaves it as a `string` which is also an object.

I'd recommend avoid using `object` and instead if you want to serialize untyped key/value pairs to instead serialize a `Dictionary<string,string>` that way the value is always stored and retrieved as a string.

Of course if you need to serialize a typed Dictionary like `Dictionary<string,bool>` then you should use that instead.

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with an *Update 1*, where I find that type information is serialized for some objects (like my custom stuff), but not for primitives. Why not for primitives, but for custom objects?

Comment: @Ted The Type information can only be included for complex types within their object literals.